# array[x].foo.push(e) adding e to the whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a this.events array storing multiple events for each day of the week.
This is how it's initialized

```
this.events = new Array(7);
for(var i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++) {
    this.events[i] = { content: [] };
}
```

I wrote this function to add events but they are added to all element of this.events rather than the corresponding day

```
this.addEvent = function(day, e) {
    this.events[day].content.push(e);
    return e;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: `addEvent` is called from this method

```
this.load = function() {
    var data = {
        from: Math.floor(this.week[0].valueOf() / 1000),
        to: Math.floor(this.week[6].valueOf() / 1000)
    };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: this.loadPath,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        context: this
    });
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    request.done(function(response) {
        var context = this;
        response = JSON.parse(response);

        response.forEach(function(event) {
            event.date = new Date(event.date);
            var thisEvent = {
                id: event.id,
                time: event.date.format('HH:MM'),
                title: event.title,
                description: event.description,
                color: event.color,
                link: event.link
            };

            context.addEvent(event.date.getRealDay(), thisEvent);
        });

        deferred.resolveWith(this);
    });
    request.fail(deferred.reject);

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Comment: What is the context here? I.e. what does `this` refer to?

Comment: Where/how is `addEvent` called?  Are you sure it is only called once?

Comment: This works just fine with just the code displayed here.  http://jsfiddle.net/ES8WL/  There must be something else going on not included in the question.  Can you try to re-create it in jsfiddle?

Comment: `this` refers to a class I wrote I edited to show where the call is made